# Including PHP files slow?

Tags: php

I am creating a dynamic website using PHP, which includes a user login system.
There is a script in every page which checks whether the user is logged in (using cookies). If not, he is redirected to the login page.
Since this script is exactly the same for every page, I am thinking of creating a separate file for it, and including that file in every page. That will make it easy to manage and make changes, if required.

My question is does "including" (using the `include` or `require` statement) the file make the execution of my main page slower? Does it have other disadvantages? Let me mention at this point that I am currently on a free host.

Also, I have already created a page (databaseDetails.php) where I am storing my database name, username and password in variables; and I am referring to it every time a page loads.
So if the answer to the first part of my question is yes, then my main page (main.php, which the user will actually view) will include the checkWhetherLoggedIn.php (which checks if the user is logged in), which in turn will be including the databaseDetails.php.

Is such a sort-of-"*nested including*" okay? Or should it be avoided?

Comment: you should use require_once or include_once or else in every script you might reinclude that file.

Comment: no it doesn't make it slower and in your case there's no real disadvantages as long as you make sure you don't include files on pages they're not needed. ie if you make a generic functions file you use often you only include it on pages where you need a function in it not on all other pages.

Comment: @Dave Well, it *will* make it slower, but certainly not noticeably so.

Comment: @deceze sure but its so minute an amount for all intents and purposes its zero.

Comment: Why not wrap the authentication in a class and then use an autoloader?

Comment: If you're using an opcode cache (like APC) then you'll never even notice that extra few nanoseconds - if you're not using an opcode cache, start using one and it will boost the performance of your pages even without includes

Comment: Thank you all for replying.
@AlexP I am not proficient in OOP. Just programming in the procedural way.

Comment: @MarkBaker My web host does not allow it. Just checked it with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Average PHP projects include (no pun intended) several dozen `include` statements and more, and they are perfectly fast enough. One or two certainly won't kill you. Splitting code up over several files is a pretty essential technique to keep large projects manageable; speeding up the minimal overhead can be mitigated by all kinds of tweaks and caches when necessary.

Worry about performance problems after you have tried it and deemed it too slow!

Comment: dozens?!? some frameworks and libraries run into the hundreds

Comment: Exactly. "Dozens and more".

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no problem to include some pages and nested includes

if you want to know exactly the difference, you can measure the script execution time with and without including your file, you will see it will almost not change

all websites use include, don't worry about include's performances. 
Don't hesitate when you want to use a include, it will make you code faster !

when you use include, you're organizing your code, so, it's more easy to understand and to edit :)